# How to get data from foreign key in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.1 for my new project smart search.
My problem is to get data from foreign key using like query for search of that table.
My database tables are:

```
  category->id, name
  search->id, category_id (foreign_key), question, answer, tags
```

My model code is:
category model

```
public function helpcenter() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\HelpCenter');
}
```

helpcenter model

```
public function category() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\HelpCenterCategory', 'id', 'category_id');
}
```

My controller function for search query is

```
$queries = HelpCenter::has('category')
  ->where('questions', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
  ->orwhere('category_id.name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
  ->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use whereHas() to subquery a relationship:

```
$queries = HelpCenter::whereHas('category', function($category) use ($term)
    {
        $category->where('name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%');
    })
  ->orWhere('questions', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
  ->take(5)->get();
```

whereHas() is documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Thank you for your answer Trip.